# Localized License Agreements in Visual Studio Setup Projects?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005, eula

I've added a EULA using VS2005's built in License Agreement UI form in a Setup Project.

This form has a LicenseFile property that you set to an RTF file that displays the EULA.

Assuming I have a number of translated RTFs, how can I make the EULA that is displayed point to the appropriate RTF localized to the user's Windows CurrentCulture settings?

I've seen some articles on WiX but at this point I need to stick with our current installation setup.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In VS you have to create a setup for each language you support. If VS enables you to localize your setup it doesn't support multilanguage setups. Therefore, if you have a specific setup for each language you have to reference the right translated licence RTF in each setup.